# Laravel Eloquent: Get value with groupBy

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, group-by, laravel-9

I am using laravel 9.x and building rest API project. I am stuck with a query group By.

I want to do get result like :

```
"data": [
        {
            "total": "1890000",
            "detail_type": [
                            {
                             "name" : "item1" 
                             "detail_type" : "1"
                            },
                            {
                             "name" : "item2" 
                             "detail_type" : "1"
                            },
                           ]
        },
        {
            "total": "350000",
            "detail_type": [
                            {
                             "name" : "item3" 
                             "detail_type" : "2"
                            },
                            {
                             "name" : "item4" 
                             "detail_type" : "2"
                            },
                           ]
        },
        {
            "total": "1960000",
            "detail_type": [
                            {
                             "name" : "item5" 
                             "detail_type" : "3"
                            },
                            {
                             "name" : "item6" 
                             "detail_type" : "3"
                            },
                           ]
        },
    ],
```

So, this is what I've tried:

```
$expenses = Expense::with('activity');
$expenses->select(Expense::raw('sum(cost*amount) as total'), 'detail_type')->orderBy('detail_type')->groupBy('detail_type')->without('activity');
```

/////////

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is the relation between detail_type and expenses? and what is the name on the detail_type object?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it may help you**

```
$expenses = Expense::with('activity')
            ->select(\DB::raw('sum(cost*amount) as total,detail_type')
                ->groupBy('detail_type')
                ->orderBy('detail_type')
                ->get();
```